# How do I change the color of the highlighted matching braces in monotouch?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, curly-braces

The highlighted color of the matching braces is difficult to see. How do I change the color to blue or red or something else more noticeable?

I have already looked in the Xamian docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize these by changing or creating a new colour scheme by going to Options >> Text Editor >> Syntax Highlighting. Hope this helps.

Comment: I overlooked and overlooked. Thank you. Spot on.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Would be nice if you set it as the answer for future users.